# How to write print statements to csv file in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset about some animal statistics. Where cat_teeth, dog_teeth, horse_teeth, and the numfeet variables are all integers.

```
            print(“Cat”,sum(cat_teeth), cat_numfeet)
            print(“Dog”,sum(dog_teeth), dog_numfeet)
            print(“Horse”,sum(horse_teeth), horse_numfeet)
```

The code above gives me

```
Cat 38 4
Dog 21 4
Horse 28 4
```

I want that same output exported to a csv file where there are 3 columns as shown above deliminated by a comma (,).

How would I do that?

```
import csv 
    with open(“results.csv”, “w”) as csvfile:
    writer= csv.writer(csvfile)
    

    writer.writerow(“Cat”,sum(cat_teeth), cat_numfeet))
    writer.writerow(“Dog”,sum(dog_teeth), dog_numfeet)     
    writer.writerow(“Horse”,sum(horse_teeth), horse_numfeet)
```

Does not work.

Comment: Instead of saying "Does not work.", can you explain the difference between the desired behavior and the observed behavior ?

Comment: Gives me an error, writerow() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`writerow` takes exactly one argument. Convert the values to a list and then call the function.

```py
writer.writerow(["Cat",sum(cat_teeth), cat_numfeet])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `print` instead of `writerow`, this is how I would do.

```
import csv 
with open("results.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    print("Animal, cat_teeth, cat_numfeet", file=csvfile)
    print(f"Cat, {sum(cat_teeth)}, {cat_numfeet}", file=csvfile)
    print(f"Dog,{sum(dog_teeth)}, {dog_numfeet}", file=csvfile)
    print(f"Horse,{sum(horse_teeth)}, {horse_numfeet}", file=csvfile)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the items into a list, don't pass them as separate arguments. Also, don't use a text editor to write your code, since those weird quotes `“”` will probably break stuff. Use an IDE like Pycharm.

```
writer.writerow(["Cat", sum(cat_teeth), cat_numfeet)])
```